# String or binary data would be truncated. Error on INSERT statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms

I'd appreciate if someone could advise on this error:

**String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated**

I'm trying to insert in column with datatype `bigint` allowing `NULL`, but get the above exception. Even if my value for this column is one digit number or NULL I still cannot insert it.
Should I change the datatype to `nvarchar`? Can this error be handled without changing the datatype?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: can you show the full INSERT statement?

Comment: Are you inserting it with quotes? That might be your problem, let us see your sql statement

Comment: This happens when you are trying to insert string literal with length greater then the column length. Are you sure this is not connected with some of the other columns in the insert statement?

Comment: Right thanks! I found out the mistake.